# Schedule a background task in Kotlin Spring boot service

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to implement a service API which does some synchronous work and schedules a background task then returns . This service is written in Kotlin and im using Global.scope to launch the background task however im not sure if its the right thing to do. Is there any recommended pattern to achive this ?

```
fun sampleApi(): ResponseEntity<String> {
        someSyncWork()
        GlobalScope.launch { longRunningFunction() }
        return ResponseEntity("Test Service Response",HttpStatusCode.valueOf(200))
    }
    
    fun someSyncWork() {
        // business logic
    }

    fun CoroutineScope.longRunningFunction() {
        launch { someBackgroundWork() }
    }

    suspend fun someBackgroundWork() {
        
        try {
            // back ground work`your text`
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            //log
        }
    }
```

Comment: `longRunningFunction` seems like a pointless intermediate step because it's launching a child coroutine inside the launched coroutine that calls it. It's rare in practice to use GlobalScope because usually you want your coroutines to be cancelled under some conditions rather than leaking memory. Are you hoping to return some result of doing the work? Right now your ResponseEntity currently is completely ignoring anything you're doing with the coroutine.

Comment: Anyway, you need to read all the coroutine documentation before you can use it. It has a high learning curve, so you can't just experiment and hope it will work the way you expect.

Comment: @Tenfour04 longRunningFunction would launch multiple async coroutines to do multiple tasks.  It needs to manage the life cycle of those coroutines so it creates its own scope

Comment: Currently it’s not creating its own scope, it’s using the scope passed to it. But it’s hard to analyze your code if the code posted isn’t what you’re actually asking about.